# How to use a Dictionary of column names to setup a DataTable structure?

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

Is there a more efficient (one-liner preferred but not necessary) way for setting up a data table column structure, rather than a foreach like what I have below?

```
// Identifiers used are:
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var columns = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Type>()
{
    { "Column 1", typeof(int) },
    { "Column 2", typeof(string) },
    { "Column 3", typeof(string) }
};

foreach (System.Collections.Generic.KeyValue<string, System.Type> column in columns)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add(column.Key, column.Value);
}
```

Comment: Just because something uses less lines in code, doesn't mean it's more efficient. Also, a one liner would _[uses almost exactly the same characters in slightly different order. And yet the one liner is harder to understand, harder to debug, and introduces closure semantics, thereby potentially changing object lifetimes in subtle ways.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)_

Comment: @Magnetron I agree totally with you, but I was just curious if there is in fact a way to do such a thing even though I would assume a foreach is pretty optimized as is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ.

```
columns.ToList().ForEach(c => dataTable.Columns.Add(c.Key, c.Value))
```

It's basically the same thing.

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't have `ForEach` extension. [Why?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/)

Comment: Is this an extension to Dictionary?

Comment: @G.LC This could only work if you convert columns to List, as List _has_ `ForEach` Method. Something like `columns.ToList().ForEach(...)`

Comment: @Magnetron Ok that is what I assumed since the link you posted mentions that List have a ForEach but Dictionary does not, so I'm assuming this is less efficient that the foreach I gave since this includes a conversion.

Comment: Could you change your answer from columns.ForEach(c => dataTable.Columns.Add(c.Key, c.Value)) to columns.ToList().ForEach(c => dataTable.Columns.Add(c.Key, c.Value)), this way the answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility using LINQ, although probably no more "efficient" other than being on a single line:

```
dataTable.Columns.AddRange(columns.Keys.Select(x => new DataColumn(x, columns[x])).ToArray());
```

This essentially casts the dictionary to an array of `DataColumn` objects and then uses the `.AddRange()` method of `DataTable.Columns` to add them to the DataTable instead of `.Add()`.

Comment: Cool solution, to be honest its hard to read as a one-liner, maybe I should alter my question to I prefer a one-liner but it is not necessary

Comment: Agreed. Most one-liner solutions are going to be harder to read to one extent or another - personally I prefer ease of legibility and maintenance over brevity :)